# Single board PC with HDMI input and output

Tags: hdmi, raspberry-pi

Are there any recommendations for a single board PC (similar to a Raspberry Pi, for example) which has both HDMI input and output ports?

Trying to catch HDMI input, modify it, and push it to a screen; any thoughts / tips greatly appreciated. My experience in this space is nil, but have a high level understanding of what the build may require

Comment: Still looking? If so, I might just recommend a separate capture card, or [this](https://embeddedmicro.com/products/hdmi-shield.html) if you're willing to go through the time and effort to program it. You could also try the [PiCapture HD1](https://lintestsystems.com/products/picapture-hd1) hat. If that doesn't work, you could also try asking on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [Raspberry Pi HDMI Input Board](http://www.geeky-gadgets.com/raspberry-pi-hdmi-input-allows-hd-recording-video-14-03-2014/). This is not really a recommendation, since I haven't used it, and there may well be better options. However, using an add-on card may well be the only solution whatever single-board computer you look at.

Comment: do you have a more recent link?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't spot the date. It's a failed Kickstarter project.

Answer (score 1):

Single board PC with HDMI out is quite common but HDMI input is quite exotic even for standard PCs. It will probably have to add on card. There are many TV capture cards and the low end is analog video. Higher end are also with HDMI in, but are much bigger and power demanding. And this will diminish the single board advantages. Are you looking for webcam video modification on the fly or real HDMI capture?

HDMI 1.0 bandwidth is defined as 4Gbit/s (1080p/60 Hz) which could not be handled by Raspberry PI.